# so on creating new event, wherein if status is Closed...that same record should automatically create in test object

Tags: apex, trigger

one custom object: Test...which has lookup relationship with Account object.

So now as we know in Account related list:> open Activities> we can create new event.

so on creating new event, wherein if status is Closed...that same record should automatically create in test object.

How can this be Achieved?

Comment: Write a trigger on event, add check for status and create record for your test object.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a trigger on Event, so for each insertion, given that its WhatId is an account, then execute some logic.

Your solution should look something like this:

```
// Map all the events to their account.
Map<Id, Event> eventsByAccount = new Map<Id, Event>();
for(Event ev : (Event[]) Trigger.new) {
    eventsByAccount.add(ev.WhatId, ev);
}

// Bring all the test records related to your accounts.
Map<Id, Test__c> testsById = new Map<Id, Test__c>([SELECT Id, Account__c FROM Test__c WHERE Account__c IN: eventsByAccount.keys()]);
List<Event> testEventsToInsert = new List<Event>();
for(Test__c test : testsById.values()) {
    // Get the event of the test's account.
    Event testEvent = eventsByAccount.get(test.Account__c);

    // Associate it to your Test__c record.
    testEvent.WhatId = test.Id;

    // Clean its Id so you can insert the new event.
    testEvent.Id = null;

    // Add it to a list for later insertion.
    testEventsToInsert.add(test);
}

// Insert all the new events related to test records.
insert testEventsToInsert;
```

Take into account that I have not compiled the code, so you might have to tune it for it to work. It is explained line by line. You would have to encapsulate this in a method, include it in a trigger and verify that the event comes from an account, etc.